# How to pass data from View in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

i want to get the value of textbox for Controller

I used `Ajax.ActionLink("Search","Result",new{id="**VALUE**"}, new AjaxOptions{...})`

```
@* This is the Index.cshtml *@
<input id="cityName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a CityName">

@Ajax.ActionLink("Search", "Result", new { id = "I want to get the cityName" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "cityInfo", LoadingElementId = "loading" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })

<div id="cityInfo"> @When I click the actionlink , the controller will return a partialview
    @Html.Partial("Result", Model)
</div>




@*This is the Result.cshtml*@
<p>
    @if (@Model!=null)
    {
        @Model.cityInfo
    }
</p>
```

this is the index.cshtml ->>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsyu0.png)

Thanks

```
public PartialViewResult Result(string cityName)//this is the controller
    {
        CityModel city = new CityModel(cityName);
        city.getInfo();
        return PartialView("Index",city);
   }
```

Comment: Your code needs to be in the question (not links to images of it). And you cannot - you need a form to submit the value of your textbox (or some javascript)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you tell me how to write the javascript,please

Comment: You need to **edit your question** to explain a bit more about what your trying to do here (My best guess is that you want some kind of 'Search' textbox and then you click the 'Search' button, you want to use ajax to display a filtered collection of some objects based on the value of the textbox?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes,I want this --> I Click the ActionLink ,the Actionlink sends the value of textbox to ResultController , then the controller will return a partial view .. But I don't know how to get the textbox's value

Comment: Then use `Ajax.BeginForm()` with `FormMethod.Get`

Answer (score -1):

You can write a function like below:

```
Ajax.ActionLink("Search","Result",new{id="id"}, new AjaxOptions{...}) //set temp value

$(document).ready(function(){
    //init value
    var value = $('#cityName').val();
    var href = $('a').attr('href').replace('id', value);
    $('a').attr('href', href);    

});
```

Comment: But when i  click the button ,the controller get  this "#btnSearch"

Comment: But new { id = "btnSearch"} can not get the value of btnSearch. it get a string  "btnSearch"

Comment: @Suen: You can update your full source code. So I can support easily.